# Adding an annotation to a class where you can't edit the source code

Tags: java, spring, aspect

I need to add an `@EntityListener` annotation to a class.  The problem is that I can't edit the source code directly.  Is it possible to add the annotation via a spring aspect or by using some other method?

Comment: via [cglib](http://ayoubelabbassi.blogspot.co.il/2011/01/how-to-add-annotations-at-runtime-to.html) or any other java code generation library

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would work with your application, but if the class and method in question are not final you may be able to extend the class, override the method adding the annotation yourself? Or maybe use the [adapter pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/adapter) to wrap the object?

Adding annotations at runtime is not possible.